# allow users from a particular group to run "dnf"command in centos

Tags: linux, centos8

How to allow all users under a particular group can only run the "dnf" command with "sudo" and without entering any password?

Answer (score 0):

first write The command `EDITOR=nano visudo` as root
you will get inside the sudo config file
now type `%TheGroupName ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` any where before the last line